# Parameter packs and move semantics

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

In the following code, a try to move-construct via parameter pack, fails.

What I am missing and how can I fix the code to run all of 4 variations?

```
#include <utility>

struct File
{
    File(const char *filename) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct InflateInput
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    InflateInput(int header, Args ...args) : source(args...) {}
    T source;
};

template<typename T>
struct DeflateInput
{
    template<typename ...Args>
    DeflateInput(int level, int header, Args ...args) : source(args...) {}
    DeflateInput(T &&stream, int level, int header) : source(std::move(stream)) {}
    T source;
};

int main()
{
    // case 1: ok
    File file{"filename"};
    DeflateInput deflate1(std::move(file), 5, 0);
    // case 2: ok
    DeflateInput deflate2(File{"filename"}, 5, 0);
    // case 3: error :-(
    InflateInput<DeflateInput<File>> inflate1(0,
        File{"filename"}, 9, 0);
    // case 4: ok
    InflateInput<DeflateInput<File>> inflate2(0,
        9, 0,
        "filename");

    return 0;
};
```

Compiler error is (-std=c++2a) the following:

```
1.cpp: In instantiation of 'InflateInput<T>::InflateInput(int, Args ...) [with Args = {File, int, int}; T = DeflateInput<File>]':
1.cpp:35:26:   required from here
1.cpp:13:58: error: no matching function for call to 'DeflateInput<File>::DeflateInput(File&, int&, int&)'
   InflateInput(int header, Args ...args) : source(args...) {}
                                                          ^
```

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: `T` in both cases is a non-deducible context. You need to provide template arguments to `DeflateInput`. I don't see how the comment `//case 1: ok` or `// case 2: ok` holds any water, when it can't even compile. Also, this should be using proper forwarding references if you really want moving to likely work as you seem to desire.

Comment: Why does `DeflateInput` have two constructors?

Comment: @WhozCraig Allowed in C++17.

Comment: @Chameleon Thanks for clarifying by adding the C++17 tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing perfect forwarding. Try below

```
template<typename ...Args>
InflateInput(int header, Args&& ...args) : source(std::forward<Args&&>(args)...) {}
```

---

Below constructor accepts an r-value reference of type `T`. But `InflateInput` is calling with a parameter(`Args`) which is an l-value. Hence the compiler error.

```
DeflateInput(T &&stream, int level, int header) : source(std::move(stream)) {}
```

You can reproduce the same error like,

```
DeflateInput deflate3(file, 5, 0)
```

---

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Oe2q68

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you are not forwarding the parameters correctly.

```
InflateInput<DeflateInput<File>> inflate1(0, File{"filename"}, 9, 0);
```

Calls the constructor

```
template<typename ...Args>
InflateInput(int header, Args ...args) : source(args...) {}
```

where `Args...` is `File, int, int`.  Since `args...` has a name, the whole packs is an lvalue, but your `DeflateInput` only accepts an rvalue reference to a `File` from

```
DeflateInput(T &&stream, int level, int header) : source(std::move(stream)) {}
```

The easiest fix is to call `std::move` on `args` like

```
InflateInput(int header, Args ...args) : source(std::move(args)...) {}
```

but what you should really do is use forwarding references along with `std::forward` to forward all the parameter perfectly.  That would change the constructor to

```
InflateInput(int header, Args&& ...args) : source(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```